# I want to concatenate two strings and the value of an EditText

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a weather API to change to the value of what is entered into an EditText box.  My weather API is this : "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=***CITY LOCATION***uk&appid=***API KEY***1&units=Imperial"

I want to make it so the CITY LOCATION part in the API is changed to whatever the value of my EditText is.  My API works if I manually enter "London", or "Liverpool" etc in the code, but I want the user to be able to enter a city of their choice, and for it to then update to the current city's weather.

Here is my code:

```
EditText editCity;

editCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCity);




String url5 = editCity.getText().toString();

String url [] = {"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + url5 + "uk&appid=fb7a0115dacfcfc60b3591a367e07181&units=Imperial"};

 JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url[0], null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try
                {
                    JSONObject main_object = response.getJSONObject("main");
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("weather");
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    String temp = valueOf(main_object.getDouble("temp"));
                    String description = object.getString("description");
                    String city = response.getString("name");
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Can you share an example of the value of url5 after you insert something in the EditText and execute de request?

Comment: At what point are you saving `editCity.getText().toString()` to `url5`? You're not showing any methods, just lines. Do you update that value and your url after the user enters the city name?

Comment: Going by what @Tim said, create a `Button`, say bGetWeather, and on click of that button capture the value of the `EditText` and call the API.